# Эмулятор Android и аппаратная виртуализация

Tags: эмулятор, виртуализация, android

После переустановки операционной системы (на Windows 10) при создании эмулятора в Android Studio я получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Your CPU does not support VT-x.

При этом, кажется, ранее, на Windows 7, эмуляторы запускались. 
Как исправить данную ошибку? Как узнать вообще, поддерживается ли точно аппаратная виртуализация для данной модели процессора? Пробовала искать по названию модели процессора (Pentium (R) Dual-Core T4300) - точно не понятно, поддерживается ли для него технология VT-x (" Эта функция может присутствовать не во всех вычислительных системах. Свяжитесь с поставщиком, чтобы получить информацию о поддержке этой функции вашей системой... ").

Не знаю, связано ли это с вопросом, но в "сведениях о системе"
параметр "Hyper-V - виртуализация включена во встроенном ПО" имеет значение "Нет", и в "компонентах Windows" видно, что компонент "Hyper-V" отключен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Могли бы сказать какой же у вас процессор, это бы немного облегчило ответ на вопрос, а поддерживает ли он VT. А вообще для начала надо заглянуть в bios, виртуализиция может быть отключена там.

Comment: @Mike, Pentium (R) Dual-Core T4300. Старенький ноут, да)

Answer (score 0):

Тоже перешел с 7 на 10.
И вроде как ранее всё работало.
Я решил проблему иначе.
Поставил haxm 6.2 вместо 7.6.5.
x86-машины работают, правда медленно.
Главное, работают.
Скорее всего, ранее работало с более старыми версиями haxm.

Answer (score -1):

HAXM не поддерживает AMD. Используй Genymotion.